# Running .NET6 SwaggerApi on a raspberrypi

Tags: c#, entity-framework, raspberry-pi, swagger, .net-6.0

i am trying to run a .Net6 Entity Framework API on my raspberrypi.

After following the Microsoft Docs and running the application, i cannot access swaggerui or API.

There are no errors poping up in console when i try to access the page via http://localhost:5000/

The webbrowser just returns a 401 Error.

Following Code:

Program.cs:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddDbContext<programContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("Context") ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("Connection string 'Context' not found.")));


builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();


var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
}
app.UseSwagger();
app.UseSwaggerUI();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

appsettings.json:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "programApiContext": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=programApi.Data;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true",
    "programContext": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=programApi.Data;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
  }
```

dotnet -info:

```
.NET SDK (gemäß "global.json"):
 Version:   6.0.301
 Commit:    43f9b18481

Laufzeitumgebung:
 OS Name:     debian
 OS Version:  11
 OS Platform: Linux
 RID:         debian.11-arm64
 Base Path:   /opt/dotnet/sdk/6.0.301/

Host (useful for support):
  Version: 6.0.6
  Commit:  7cca709db2

.NET SDKs installed:
  6.0.301 [/opt/dotnet/sdk]

.NET runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.6 [/opt/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.6 [/opt/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]

To install additional .NET runtimes or SDKs:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet-download
```

nginx-site config:

```
server {
    listen        80;
    location / {
        proxy_pass         http://localhost:5000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   Connection keep-alive;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```

Comment: A "401 error" means "Unauthorized". Have you tried removing `app.UseAuthentication();` and `app.UseAuthorization();`?

Comment: are sure it is 401 error, can you put some screenshot of browser error.

Comment: [The docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/getting-started-with-swashbuckle?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#add-and-configure-swagger-middleware) say `Launch the app and navigate to https://localhost:<port>/swagger/v1/swagger.json.` for the Swagger document and `The Swagger UI can be found at https://localhost:<port>/swagger`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To retrieve the Swagger document you need to use its full path. From the [Get started with Swashbuckle and ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/getting-started-with-swashbuckle?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#add-and-configure-swagger-middleware) docs:

> Launch the app and navigate to **https://localhost:/swagger/v1/swagger.json**. The generated document describing the endpoints appears as shown in OpenAPI specification (openapi.json).
>
> The Swagger UI can be found at **https://localhost:/swagger**. Explore the API via Swagger UI and incorporate it in other programs.

You have to use extra code to display the UI at the root

> To serve the Swagger UI at the app's root (https://localhost:/), set the RoutePrefix property to an empty string:

```
app.UseSwaggerUI(options =>
{
    options.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "v1");
    options.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;
});
```

Comment: It looks like i got it fixed, at least running on localhost. Via Network it still wont work, probably a nginx config error.

While testing on localhost i encounterd another problem: My app is configured to use mssql as entity framework context.

Wich alternative for mssql would you suggest running on the raspberry?

Comment: Try SQLite. SQL Server *can* run on Linux but there's no ARM version

Answer (score 1):

After launch your application follow bellow link to get swagger

```
https://localhost:5000/swagger/index.html
```

Check your **launchSettings.json**

```
    "development": {
    "commandName": "Project",
    "dotnetRunMessages": true,
    "launchBrowser": true,
    "launchUrl": "swagger",
    "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5000",
    "environmentVariables": {
      "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "development"
    }
  }
```